# Stored Procedure Call from Powerbuilder cursor error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, powerbuilder

I am having some issues calling a stored procedure.  I get an error that "the cursor is not open" when it tries to FETCH the output.  The stored procedure simply returns the next record number off a stack and increments it up by 1.

I can get the procedure to execute with no errors, the error pops in the FETCH section.

```
String ls_recnum
ls_recnum = Space(100)

connect using sqlca;

DECLARE sproc_getevent PROCEDURE FOR dbo.sp_getevent 
    @result = :ls_recnum OUTPUT 
USING SQLCA;

EXECUTE sproc_getevent;
If sqlca.SQLCode < 0 Then
    MessageBox( "Error Calling proc - sp_getevent", sqlca.SQLErrText,    StopSign!)
    Return
End If

FETCH sproc_getevent INTO :ls_recnum;
If sqlca.SQLCode < 0 Then
    MessageBox( "Error Fetching proc - sp_getevent", sqlca.SQLErrText, StopSign!)
    Return
End If

CLOSE sproc_getevent;
MessageBox("RecNum", ls_recnum)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `sqlca.SQLCode` and `sqlca.SQLErrText` evaluate to?

Comment: How are you connecting to the DB, ODBC?, OLE DB?, something else?

Comment: ODBC for connecting.